# WEB API2 / HTTP DELETE is not triggering - 405 error

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, webapi2

Hi i am trying to delete the record (HttpDelete).the method in the controller is not triggering and getting 405 Method Not Allowed error.

jquery below

```
 function deleteContract(contractId) {
            var contract = new Object();
            contract.ContractID = "ContractId";
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: 'DELETE',
                data: contract,
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'http://localhost:4233/api/Contract/DeleteContractById/' + contractId,
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
               alert("deleted successfully")
            }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
            })
        }
```

controller below

```
 // DELETE: api/Contract/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Contract))]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpDelete]
    [ActionName("DeleteContractById")]
    //[Route("api/Contract/{id}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteContract(Guid id)
    {
        Contract contract = db.Contract.Find(id);
        if (contract == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Strata.Remove(contract);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, contract);
    }
```

webapiconfig below

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
                config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ControllerAndAction",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "GET", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

    }
```

web config below

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>

  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
   <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

when i make the call using fiddler its working fine. let me know if i have missed out any settings in the code.

Thanks
Dev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

Comment: Please take a look at these existing questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: I have had this issue before and I _disabled_ WebDav for the application pool that my website was hosted on.

Comment: please look athttps://stackoverflow.com/a/55134621/4746570

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use async syntax? Like

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteStrata(Guid id)
...
await db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: The error is a 405 Method Not Allowed.  The server is actively refusing the connection.  Sadly changing it to Async won't solve this issue to allow the server to accept the HTTP request using the DELETE HTTP verb.

Comment: Sorry for a late response. Think, my suggestion was a not well-thought. Now I don't think it would help. The problem lies somewhere else and I don't know where. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten 405's when the method I was using was not what the API was expecting. And I did notice a few things though I'm not sure these are the underlying problems:

1. The action name on the API is misspelled, it should be DeleteContractById (it has contract in place of contract).
2. The deleteContract function is passing a body. The API method does not expect a body (data).
3. The route is setup to expect a GUID id. Is the value of ContractId passed into deleteContract a valid GUID?

Comment: I have corrected the spelling mistake "deletecontractbyid". in the source code its correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the solution by doing below changes

**web.config**

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
</customHeaders>
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

Declare the below in class level

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:49369", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header")]
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); // newly added this require to "Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors"
}
```

**Controller**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:49369", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header")]
public class ContractController : ApiController
{
}
```

**WebApi.config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Controllers with Actions
        // To handle routes like `/api/VTRouting/route`
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ControllerAndAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "GET", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }  
}
```

That's all it started working.

Comment: I take it that you're accepting GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS requests from other domains if you're enabling CORS?  If you're not, then I don't think you should be enabling it.