# How Many Delete or Put methods in a WebApi Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with ASP.NET WebAPI`. I wanted to keep in RESTful API, so I create some apis in one controller, such as:

- GET `/api/user/`  - userslist
- GET `/api/user/{id}`  - a user
- GET `/api/user/{id}/books`  - get all books of the user
- Delete `/api/user/{id}`  - delete the user
- Delete `/api/user/{id}/books` - delete users' books

All the `Get` methods works fine, but only one `Delete` method can work, when the other was called, it will got a `405` response. Could you help me ?

Thanks.  here is my controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Car")]//AttributeRouting asp.net 4.0 (not 5.0)
public class CarController : ApiController
{
    public CarInfoPagedList GetCarInfos(int page = 0, int limit = 10)
    {  
        var list = new CarInfoPagedList();
        return list;
    }

    [HttpRoute("{id}")]
    public string GetCarById(string id, string time = " ") 
    {
        return "some";
    }


    [HttpRoute("{id}/runtime")]
    public CarState GetCarRuntime(string id) {
        return new CarState(id);
    }

    [DELETE("{id}")]//405
    public void DeleteCar(string id)
    {
        //TODO:remove car
    }

    [DELETE("{id}/terminal/{terminalId}")]//work fine
    public void Delete(string id, string terminalId) 
    {
    }

    [PUT("{id}/")]//405
    public void PutCar(string id, CarInfo car)
    {
    }

    [PUT("{id}/terminal/{terminalId}")]//work fine
    public void Put(string id, string terminalID) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual controller?

Comment: Try to add some code, it is a little complicated to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed

Comment: Have you tried defining the verbs on ALL methods? I had a similar problem because two routes were different only based on the verbs they used.

Comment: Did you try decorating that method as `[HttpDelete][Route("{id}"]`

Comment: @MegaTron yes I did. but that question has only one delete method, I have two, and one of them can work , the other responses 405.

Comment: When I append some words at the end of urls , all of them can work.
delete /api/cars/{id}/name
delete /api/cars/{id}/type
but delete /api/cars/{id} can't work.

Comment: @Da Zhang, the problem is you have multiple routes with the same path, that only differ on the verb. Put the httpget/httpput/httpdelete attributes on all of them.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWatts , you are right