# ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebAPI 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Setup**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2017 Professional
- ASP.Net Core 2.2

**What I'm trying to do**

Run an Integration Test against a controller method in my Web API that uses a `PATCH` verb

**MyController.cs**

```csharp
namespace FluidIT.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private readonly IMyQueries _myQueries;

        public JobsController(IMediator mediator, IMyQueries myQueries)
        {
            _mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
            _myQueries = myQueries ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myQueries));
        }

        // PATCH: api/v1/my/{id}
        [Route("id:int")]
        [HttpPatch]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveMeAsync(int id)
        {
            bool commandResult = false;

            try
            {
                commandResult = await _mediator.Send(new RemoveMeCommand(id));
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (NotFoundException)
            {
                return NotFound(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyIntegrationTest.cs**

```csharp
[Fact]
async Task Patch_MyAsync_WhenIdNotFound_ReturnsNotFoundStatusCode()
{
    // Arrange
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri($"{_fixture.Client.BaseAddress}{_baseRoute}/1"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Patch,
        Headers =
        {
            { HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8.ToString() },
            { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json" }
        }
    };

    // Act
    var response = await _fixture.Client.SendAsync(request);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response.StatusCode);
}
```

**What I've done so far**

I've seen that this is a fairly common occurrence when trying to use the `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` http verbs.  I've also seen that adding the following to a `web.config` file to remove the `webDAV` module from IIS is the suggested solution

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed)
[A blog post](https://hovercraft.ie/asp-net-core-web-api-put-delete-methods-not-allowed-405-error/)

**web.config**

```csharp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
          <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
          </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, as you've probably guessed, this solution isn't working for me.  My test returns a `405 MethodNotAllowed` response.

Most of the info on this topic seem to be from a while ago, so I thought I'd ask the question here specifically for an ASP.NET Core API.

Comment: Shouldn't route attribute be written like this `[Route("{id:int}")]` to specify route constraint? Also, have you tried testing your endpoint using POSTMAN or Fiddler?

Comment: *Facepalm*, I've been looking at this for 2 days now!!  Thank you Moshin.

Comment: I got a similar error because of defining two [HttpPost] for one Action. So when I submitted the button, the program was confused(getting error 405) as to which action should I start .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To fix the issue, correct the route constraint syntax enclose the parameter and datatype inside curly braces `[Route("{id:int}")]`

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveMeAsync(int id)
{
    bool commandResult = false;

    try
    {
        commandResult = await _mediator.Send(new RemoveMeCommand(id));
        return NoContent();
    }
    catch (NotFoundException)
    {
        return NotFound(id);
    }
}
```