# Laravel Azure App Service Delete Method Not Allowed

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hosting a laravel app in Azure's App Service and every time the web application makes DELETE requests, it throws up 405 Method Not Allowed and returns the message below:

`The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.`

I've exhausted all options I could find in the internet and tried all stuff mentioned. Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses .NET WebAPI, you may get a 405 Method Not Allowed error when you issue a PUT or DELETE request.
This error is caused because the [WebDAV module intercepted the request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis)

In your web.config, try to insert this code

```
<system.webServer>    
  <modules>        
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
  </modules>    
  <handlers>        
    <remove name="WebDAV" />    
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And this issue duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: Not familiar with .NET WebAPI. Application is built with Laravel.