# ASP.net core 405 error When trying to parse value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-core

I Understand what my error is. from other answers like
[Asp.Net Core 3.1 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850457/asp-net-core-3-1-405-method-not-allowed)
and I can see that one of the solutions is javascript or not.
I also understand the reason I am gettign 405 is cause my [HTTPGET] request is blocked.
What I am trying to do here is really simple. I want to send the  imdbID to my controller here is my code...

Controller :  From what I gather I access the controller and the reason this happens is cause imdbID is null. I get nothing in my console.write

```
[Route("api/Movies")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult FindMovie(string imdbID)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(imdbID);  
            var item = _db.Movies.Where(s => s.imdbID.Equals(imdbID)).FirstOrDefault();
              if (item != null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
           return View();
        }
```

and here is the view ... from where I try to send imdbID I am trying to do it via imdbID

```
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Search)
            {
                @item.Runtime
                //       each table row is assigned with the imdbID returned from the API. if the user clicks one of the rows
                //then the system will 1st check the database if this movie exist in the database. if not then it will be added and then desplayed
                //if the movie exist then it will be automatically desplayed to the user without making another API call.
                <tr >
                    <td><img src="@item.Poster" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" width="200"> </td>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Year</td>
                    <td>  <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FindMovie" asp-for="@item.imdbID">Back to List</a> </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Comment: I'm not sure Console.WriteLine() works in ASP.NET Core controllers. But you use a logger to log to the console.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply Console.writeline() works okay, I have it tested. from the other parts of the controller just to check if it passes from the correct places. but logging is not my problem. the problem here is that I get a 405 error and cant find how to fix it

Comment: Your API accepts only HTTP Post request and with <a> tag what is actually going out is an HTTP GET request. You need to change your API to accept HTTP GET request.

Comment: Yeah that worked out. it pointed to me that my _db is now null but this is not the same issue. thanks for helping me time for me to continue learning. again thanks